# os.listdir returns list with mysterious characters

Tags: python, list

I'm doing `os.listdir()` on a directory, and it returns a list like this:

```
[u'Somefile.gif', u'SomeDirectory', u'SomeJPEG.jpeg']
```

What are the u's for? In my searches, I've heard that this:

1. Is a fixed bug.
2. Means the listed items are unicode.

I don't believe either of these to be true.

Comment: re #2 .. why don't you believe it? Just curious (not saying it's unicode)

Comment: @Levon because none of the filenames contain unicode, and listdir has never done this before.

Comment: @tkbx: Unicode is not just for non-English characters, so technically speaking, your strings *do* contain Unicode text.

Comment: @AndréCaron but no characters that aren't ASCII, UTF, or something like that be default, right?

Comment: @tkbx: I have no idea what your last comment means :-|

Comment: The strings contain all characters that are available in Unicode, but because there is a different Unicode type than the default string type, the string "SomeDirectory" should not be Unicode be default, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python2, the `u` in `u'...'` indicates the object is unicode.

[From the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> Changed in version 2.3: On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if path is a
>   Unicode object, the result will be a list of Unicode objects.
>   Undecodable filenames will still be returned as string objects.

Perhaps you are calling `os.listdir` with a unicode argument. For example:

```
In [51]: import os

In [52]: os.listdir('.')
Out[52]: ['a', 'a.ps']

In [53]: os.listdir(u'.')
Out[53]: [u'a', u'a.ps']
```

Comment: Weird. I'm using `tempFilesList = os.listdir(dirRenamed)`, and tried with a new directory, filenames "1.txt", "2.jpeg", and "3" (directory), and I still get [u]

Comment: Try `print(type(dirRenamed))` to see if `dirRenamed` is unicode.

Comment: <type 'unicode'>. Since letters and spaces don't require unicode, can I convert the list to the non-unicode standard ("string") somehow?

Comment: You don't really want to convert to the standard string...dealing with unicode filenames is ultimately a better choice IMHO.

Comment: Will it being unicode cause problems with os and shutil moving the file, etc?

Comment: It won't cause any problem, especially if you know [the absolute minimum every software developer must know about unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `u` prefix on your `str`s let you know that these are in fact unicode strings. Calling `str` on them will turn the unicode strings into "normal" python strings. However, this is only that simple if your file/directory names are made up of strictly ascii characters.

```
In [2]: L
Out[2]: [u'asdf', u'asdf', u'aasf']

In [3]: [str(i) for i in L]
Out[3]: ['asdf', 'asdf', 'aasf']
```

Hope this helps